# Changes to theme not being represented in browser

Tags: theme, customize

I am currently working on a Magento store.

There is a 3rd party price tag that shows when viewing a product.

The original price is sometimes displayed as plain text next to the image of the product.  When this is the case the 3rd party price tag works fine.  However, sometimes the plain text original price isn't there, instead the price is in a different element, overlapping the "add to cart" button.
When the latter is the case, the 3rd party price tag wont appear (presumably because it can't find a price to display).

I am currently trying to modify the stores theme so that it will check for the presence of the text price tag and if it is not there then instead use the price from the button.

In doing this I'm stuck, it seems non of the changes I make to the theme are showing up when I reload the page.  I've checked to make sure I'm modifying the right theme.

Even just adding a simple div or text block, I'm looking seeing anything come through on the live site.

The data I'm editing is in: app/design/frontend/efv1/default/template
Efv1 is confirmed as the currently active theme.

With normal price tag -
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDdXR.png

With normal price tag missing -
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgFZx.png

Comment: Have you flushed all caches? Failing that, recompiling the frontend?

Comment: Do you mean my browser or Magento?

Comment: Magento's caching

Comment: Clearing Magento's cache was the solution, thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Clearing Magento's server-side cache was the solution to seeing the updated site.